# Установка библиотеки pycades для Ubuntu

Tags: python, установка

Устанавливаю библиотеку pycades на Python для работы с КриптоПро на Ubuntu.
Собрал успешно расширение по инструкции https://docs.cryptopro.ru/cades/pycades/pycades-build
В результате получается файл pycades.so
Следующий шаг установка

В инструкции написано

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'/path_to_pycades_so')
import pycades
```

Проделываю в VisualStudioCode

Вместо 'path_to_pycades_so' подставляю свой путь
'/home/konstantin/python_projects/pycades_test/build/pycades.so'

Результат: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycades'`

Пробовал разные вариации '/usr/python_projects/pycades_test/build/pycades.so' и './python_projects/pycades_test/build/pycades.so' и прочие
Результат тот же

Согласно той же инструкции экспортировал путь в системную переменную

```
echo 'export PYTHONPATH=/path_to_pycades_so' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

В этом случае расширение будет доступно по умолчанию.

```
>>> import pycades

>>> pycades.ModuleVersion()
```

должен быть результат: "0.1.19595"

также вместо /path_to_pycades_so указывал разные пути

Результат: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycades'`

В линуксе не силен. Поэтому прошу помощи сообщество. Если можно подробнее

Comment: "Вместо 'path_to_pycades_so' подставляю свой путь '/home/konstantin/python_projects/pycades_test/build/pycades.so'" - в PATH нужно добавлять путь к директории, в которой лежит so библиотека, а не путь к самому файлу. Также `echo 'export PYTHONPATH=...' >> ~/.bashrc` каждый раз добавляет новую строку экспорта в файл `.barshrc`. Рекомендую открыть этот файл, руками убрать лишние строки.

Answer (score 0):

Ежели ещё актуально, у меня импортируется, если проделать

```
echo 'export PYTHONPATH=/path_to_pycades_so' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

где path_to_pycades_so - путь к директории с pycades.so, не к самому файлу